# WebApi 2 Route not resolving with guid as parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have a class defined below, and hitting it with the following urls

This url works:
http://rooturl.com/website/api/v1/queuedNotifications

This url does not
http://rooturl.com/website/api/v1/queuedNotifications/4b2a366b-e349-468d-99e6-b60918dc79f9

This url does not
http://rooturl.com/website/api/v1/notifications/4b2a366b-e349-468d-99e6-b60918dc79f9

It's not recognizing the GUID on the end of the url as a paramter to the GET. can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?  I placed the constraint on the route prefix for a GUID and the parameter names match...  not sure what is up.

I get a 404.0 Error with the urls that don't work

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Error Summary</legend>
<h2>HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found</h2>
<h3>The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
</fieldset>
```

Class definition

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1")]
[Authorize]
public class NotificationsService : BaseApiService
{
    private readonly INotificationsService _notificationsService;

    public NotificationsService(INotificationsService notificationsService)
    {
        _notificationsService = notificationsService;
    }

    #region UserNotifications

    [Route("notifications/{userId:guid}")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public async Task<List<UserNotificationModel>> GetNotifications(Guid userId)
    {
        return await _notificationsService.GetNotifications(userId);
    }

    [Route("notification")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public async Task<UserNotificationModel> CreateNotifications(UserNotificationModel model)
    {
        return await _notificationsService.CreateNotification(model);

    }
    #endregion


    #region Queued Notifications
    [Route("queuedNotifications")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public async Task<List<NotificationsQueueModel>> GetQueuedNotifications()
    {
        return await _notificationsService.GetQueuedNotifications();
    }

    [Route("queuedNotifications/{userId:guid}")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public async Task<List<NotificationsQueueModel>> GetQueuedNotifications(Guid userId)
    {
        return await _notificationsService.GetQueuedNotifications(userId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. When I'm creating a new Controller (deriving from ApiController) all works fine. (Changed Return to Ok() and IHttpActionResult).